# Best way to build video chat into a website?

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming, html5-video, videochat

Feel like I'm really exhausting my options with browser based video chat.

Looking for a solution that has support on the highest number of browser setups possible, and and a good level of call quality (including acoustic echo cancellation).

Here was my process:

- To be more future-ready, I tried services like Tokbox, Bistri, Quickblox, etc but the service only worked well on Chrome and Firefox
- Tried VideoIO.swf but could not connect to other PCs with it (multiple browsers on same PC were fine)
- Tried other chat services like CamChat (camchatscript.com) but same problem as above (likely the peer-to-peer issue - tested and issue wasn't specific to my network)
- Could not find a service that offers setup and an API like Tokbox for a Flash-based video chat system that uses a media server, but would this be the way to go? How would I start down this route? Is there a sample somewhere I could use for testing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found any answer or possible solution for your project? I am having the same issue here and cannot find any good API for chat that is not based on WebRTC (we need to support IE without any plugins)